# Importing all files in a folder

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I need to import over 100 CSV files in to a new access table

I am struggling with the code to be honest any help is appreciated. This is what I have so far:

```
Option Compare Database

Dim sql
Dim rs

Const strPath As String = "C:\Folder\" 'Directory Path

sql = "Select * from FileNames"

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sql)

rs.MoveFirst

Do Until rs.EOF

'docmd.TransferText rs("fileName")
DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelimi, , "FileNames", strPath, True

rs.MoveNext

Loop
```

I already have a table that has both the filepath and file name in. The format is as such:

> C:\Folder\File17-08-01.csv

Comment: You aren't constructing the filename into your strPath from your recordset, so there is nothing going to import. 
You also aren't declaring what your variables are.

Comment: What Minty said, plus `acImportDelimi` should not have that i at the end. Also, your code doesn't seem to be wrapped in a sub, and is missing `Option Explicit`, which you should be using

Comment: What does your code do? Does it break? Where? What error message(s) do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the "FileNames" recordset and import each file using the [TransferText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/docmd-transfertext-method-access) method.

Change "YourTableName" to the name of the table the files should be imported.

```
Public Sub ImportFiles()
    On Error GoTo ErrorTrap

    Const strPath As String = "C:\Folder\"

    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Set rs = CurrentDb().OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM FileNames", dbOpenSnapshot)
    With rs
        If .EOF Then GoTo Leave
        .MoveLast
        .MoveFirst
    End With

    Dim idx As Long
    For idx = 1 To rs.RecordCount
        DoCmd.TransferText TransferType:=acImportDelim, _
                           TableName:="YourTableName", _
                           FileName:=strPath & rs![FileName], _
                           HasFieldNames:=True
        rs.MoveNext
    Next idx

Leave:
    On Error Resume Next
        rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

ErrorTrap:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume Leave
End Sub
```